# HTML5 Server Sent Events using Java Servlet 3 and tomcat

Tags: html, tomcat, server-sent-events

I tried to run this code in Eclipse   with Tomcat but I don't get any output by the server in the client side. Should I include some libriries (jar files, js files ... ) to the project ? Thank you.

**Here the two files:**

```
<html>
<body onload ="registerSSE()" >
    <script>
        function registerSSE()
        {
            alert('test 1');
            var source = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/hello/sse');  
            alert('Test2');
            source.onmessage=function(event)
            {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br />";
            };
            /*source.addEventListener('server-time',function (e){
                alert('ea');
            },true);*/
        }
    </script>
    <output id ="result"></output>

</body>
</html>
```

the servlet :

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class sse extends HttpServlet {
   public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            System.out.println("SSE Demo");
            response.setContentType("text/event-stream");

            PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
            int i=0;
            while(true) {
                i++;
                pw.write("event: server-time\n\n");  //take note of the 2 \n 's, also on the next line.
                pw.write("data: "+ i + "\n\n");
                System.out.println("Data Sent!!!"+i);
                if(i>10)
                break;
            }
            pw.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
        doPost(request,response);
    }

}
```

Which version of tomcat should I need ? and also which connector type should i require?

_ WEB.XML *_*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>demo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>sse</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>sse</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>sse</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: What you are getting in response ?

Comment: Also try to open resource in browser itself - http://frewper:8080/hello/sse

Comment: @Ved I get nothing . I try to open the page in my browser but i have the same. no result!

Comment: Your Web.xml seems not to contain proper path to your servlet. show complete code here to get precise answers.

Comment: @Souad just out of curiosity can u confirm and tell me what is the name of your machine!!!

Comment: @frewper sorry I copied the code directly from the tutorial. localhost excuse me.

Comment: And also pls post the error details only then can issue be figured out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about EventResource, but I understand that, if you are able to open resource in browser, it should take you one step ahead.

Make changes as under in web.xml :-

1. `<servlet-class>` Give full path to your servlet with package name like - `com.test.sse`
2. `<url-pattern>` You can make `/*` here so it will work for every URL.

After making this changes, try to open resource in browser and see if this helps.

Comment: I don't get the error any more now and i see the message `System.out.println("Data Sent!!!"+i);` in the console but after runing the project open a window for download not HTML  page in the browser ...

Comment: I delete this line `response.setContentType("text/event-stream");` then the page still loading and it cannot stop because of the loop WHILE. I think the server doesn't append the text but replace it that's why the server cannot show the content of the page. what do you think?

Comment: If You are opening it in browser, change code like this - `response.setContentType("text/html");`

Comment: Euuh ... as i say before the page still loading and i have no output from server but any way there is no error!

Comment: Hmm. Your Servlet is not able to opened. Try to give URL pattern like - `/Test` and then type `http://localhost:8080/hello/Test`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32391/discussion-between-ved-and-souad)

Comment: I change now the URL pattern and I get the alert is this line : ` alert('Test2');` and nothing else